# Showing for any real number $\lfloor a\rfloor+1>a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This seem a simple proposition

For any real number a $\lfloor a\rfloor+1>a$

For any example
$\lfloor 2.9\rfloor=2$

$\lfloor 3.1\rfloor=3$

$\lfloor 4\rfloor=4$

I think this is obvious. Because a number with decimals and take out the decimals and add 1 it would be bigger than the number with decimals.

Comment: how are you defining $\lfloor a\rfloor$? once you specifically have that it should be obvious

Comment: if you are defining it as I think u are, then you are always removing a part that is strictly less than 1 and then adding the full 1 back. So clearly the inequality holds. Which is exactly what u wrote in ur question anyway, so Im not sure if I provided too much new information. What in  particular bothers u? Write down the definitions and it should be easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume the contrary, $\lfloor a\rfloor +1 \le a$.

Then consider $\lfloor a\rfloor + 1$, which is a larger integer less than or equal to $a$. This contradicts to the definition of floor function:

> $\lfloor a\rfloor$ is the maximum of those integers that are smaller or equal to $a$.

Answer (score 2):

The proposition is correct. For each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ the number $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is defined as the unique integer $a$ that satisfies the inequality $a \le x < a + 1$. Therefore $x < \lfloor x \rfloor + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers, it may also help to first think of what $a-\lfloor{a}\rfloor$ equals. For instance, if $a=2.9$, as you have given, $a-\lfloor{a}\rfloor=0.9.$

If $a=-3.1$, $\lfloor{a}\rfloor=-4$, so that $a-\lfloor{a}\rfloor=0.1$ (why?).

If $a=2$, $\lfloor{a}\rfloor=2$, so that $a-\lfloor{a}\rfloor=0$.

We see then that $a-\lfloor{a}\rfloor$ is the "decimal part" of your real number $a$, so to speak. As such, $0 \leq a-\lfloor{a}\rfloor < 1$, meaning that $$\lfloor{a}\rfloor \leq a < \lfloor{a}\rfloor+1$$

which is what we wanted to show (actually, a little bit more!).